# How to update date field automatically from a timestamp field in Mysql 5.5?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an InnoDB table with a timestamp in it, and I wish to have another field which carries only the date part of the timestamp, so that I can create an index on it. (My temporal queries will always be bound by date, so having an index with high cardinality on the timestamp is not really needed.)

Is it possible to have the date field update automatically `ON UPDATE` from the timestamp field (similar to how `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` works)?

I tried the following but it MySQL says I have an error in my SQL syntax.

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `full_ts` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The full timestamp',
  `only_date` date NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE date(full_ts) COMMENT 'This field carries only the date part of the full timestamp for better indexing.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ONLY_DATE_IDX` (`only_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I could of course update both fields everywhere in the code, but it would be cleaner if the `only_date` field was a slave of the `full_ts` field, updated and kept consistent by the database.

I know that in MySQL 5.7.5 there was a new feature added for stored generated columns, which seem to do exactly this. Unfortunately it is not possible to upgrade the database version at the moment.

Is there a way to achieve this in MySQL 5.5?

Comment: Create a trigger that manages it.

Comment: I don't think you can do that easily. You can't modify the same table that caused the trigger to execute.

Comment: What??? That's what you use triggers for.

Comment: You can manipulate the columns of the current row in a trigger with select or 'set'. You just cannot change other rows in the sme table (mutate).

Comment: @RyanVincent OK thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This will update the "only_date" column when you update the "full_ts" column

```
CREATE TRIGGER `autoDate` BEFORE UPDATE ON `test_table` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.only_date=DATE(NEW.full_ts);
END
```

**EDIT:**
For further reading on triggers, please refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html

Also worth reading about triggers https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/faqs-triggers.html